# how to prevent R Studio from altering header titles when the first column of an imported data set contains dates

Tags: r, read.csv

I want to import a CSV file into R. The CSV has date as the first column. When I load the CSV file into R it takes the data from the date column and creates a new column but does not attach the column title "date" to the column. It then essentially shifts the headers to the right and creates a new column with no data in it.

For instance.

**The CSV file is structured as follows**

column 1 header is "dates" and the column contains dates

column 2 header is "price" and the column contains prices

column 3 header is "quantity" and the column contains quantities

There is no 4th column

**after being imported into R Studio it is structured as follows**

column 1 has no header and the column contains dates

column 2 header is "dates" and the column contains prices

column 3 header is "price" and the column contains quantities

column 4 header is  quantity and the column contains N/A in each cell

**My code is as follows**

```
data1 <- read.csv("prices.csv")
data1
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you constructed this from an Excel worksheet. You should probably edit the csv file with a text editor to remove the extra comma in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example that simply takes the data you already have imported and shifts the column names, removing the last column.

```
# Create dummy data
data1 <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3),
                    dates = c(4, 5, 6),
                    price = c(7, 8, 9),
                    quantity = c(10, 11, 12))
str(data1)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#   $ X       : num  1 2 3
#   $ dates   : num  4 5 6
#   $ price   : num  7 8 9
#   $ quantity: num  10 11 12

# Replace column names 1:3 with column names 2:4
colnames(data1)[1:3] <- colnames(data1)[2:4]
# Remove fourth column from data.frame
data1[[4]] <- NULL
str(data1)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ dates   : num  1 2 3
#   $ price   : num  4 5 6
#   $ quantity: num  7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I simply opened the csv file on another computer and saved it without making any alterations to it, then imported it into R. It then worked.

This makes me believe that it is something to do with an Excel setting that was on the original computer but I do not know for sure if that is the case.